# Doctrine Many-to-one multiple target entities

Tags: doctrine

I'm using Doctrine ORM for my project and I have an issue with my tables :

- device (id, name, ip_address)
- device_group (id, name)
- template (id, object_type, object_id)

So these three entities extend from a superclass for common fields such as ID, timestamp...

If we take a look at the template entity, the object_id field refers either to device.id or device_group.id, depending on the value of object_type (a string that can be 'device' or 'group'). I would like to know how to make a relationship that has multiple targets, if possible.

**Device_group :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Doctrine\Repositories\DeviceGroup")
 * @ORM\Table(name="device_group")
 */
class DeviceGroup extends BaseModel
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

}
```

**Device**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Doctrine\Repositories\Device")
 * @ORM\Table(name="device")
 */
class Device extends BaseModel
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="ip_address", length=45)
     */
    protected $ip_address;
}
```

**Template**

```
**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Doctrine\Repositories\Template")
 * @ORM\Table(name="template")
 */
class DevicePart extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="object_type", length=6)
     */
    protected $object_type;//can be 'group' or 'device'

    /**
     * Many DevicePart have one Object
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="?????????")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $objects;

    //target entity can be : App\Doctrine\Entities\Device" or "App\Doctrine\Entities\DeviceGroup

}
```

I heard about inheritance mapping and I already implement that with my superclass, I looked at some examples but that would make me create new tables, the thing is I have to keep the current structure as the data are used by other programs (SQL Alchemy with Python scripts).

Do you have any idea ?

Thanking you in advance,